# Unable to create binding using current selection and specified binding type

Tags: office-js

I'm currently using Microsoft Office Professional in version 16.0.4266.1001, and it has Word JavaScript API 1.1.

My function `addFromSelectionAsync` stopped working but I'm sure it worked recently. The `result.status` is `Failed`. Here is my code:

[image]

And here are error message I get:

> Error: Unable to create binding using current selection and specified binding type.

I'm sure `Office.BindingType.Text` is correct because I'm selecting text in the document

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Instead of _code as image_ edit the question and paste your code. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) link how to ask good question.

Comment: Is this happening in multiple documents regardless of text that is selected or only specific text in a specific document?